# Subnets or VLANs?

Tags: networking, router, lan

I have a network with multiple groups of people that I want to secure and separate. Here are the groups

1. company devices (wired and wireless)
2. center devices (wired and wireless)
3. visitor devices (wired)
4. customer devices (wired and wireless)

I'm trying to figure out whether subnets for each or VLANs are best. Here's the hardware I have

1. cable modem in bridge mode
2. firewall/router (2-port LAN)
3. Routerboard router (4-port LAN)
4. TP-Link SG1024de switch (smart switch)
5. various unmanaged switches
6. Ubiquiti AP

I'd like to have internal LAN and WAN devices have unrestricted access to each other, including to my servers including DHCP and file server.

My customer devices need only Internet access and access to my file server. This could be wired-only if need be, but wireless as well would be handy.

My renter devices need access only to their other devices both wireless and wired.

My visitors need only wireless access to Internet, nothing internal.

So, should I subnet everything? Would I need to install additional WAPs? Or should I VLAN everything? Can I tag VLANs or force SSIDs to work on a certain subnet?

Any other advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually subnets go together *with* VLANs (i.e. one subnet per VLAN), just like separate physical LANs. (Your router also sees them similar to separate physical interfaces.) There is no security in putting two subnets on the same (V)LAN since they're directly reachable from each other (with, at most, a sneaky IP address change), and there is no sense in using the same subnet across two (V)LANs since that kinda goes against the *definition* of "subnet".

So you would create one subnet *and* one VLAN for each group; connect the router to one of the TP-Link's ports configured as a "trunk" port (or at least, with all VLANs tagged), and assign the other ports to specific VLANs (untagged), where they go to unmanaged switches.

That router would be serving DHCP to all VLANs, act as their gateway outside the subnet, and as firewall for access between VLANs.

SSIDs are like ports on a switch, so they'll only be in separate subnets if they belong to different (V)LANs. Many higher-end APs support multiple SSIDs with separate VLANs, but it depends on which kind of "Ubiquiti AP" exactly you have. (I heard the UniFi series supports this, but I've only worked with airMAX devices which definitely don't.)

(These multi-VLAN APs would also connect to a "trunk" port, I think.)

Comment: I think that puts me on my way. Thank you. A couple small clarifications that don't change much:
1. Windows server is my DHCP server.
2. It is a Unifi AP. 

Thank you.

Comment: Well, I suppose the router will have to act as a DHCP relay then.